# Find real values of a,b,c, such that $f_{a,b,c}$ is a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For which values of a, b and c is $f_{a,b,c}$ a linear transformation? [10 marks]

$f_{a,b,c}\ :\left[ \begin{array}{c}
x \\ 
y \end{array}
\right]=\left[ \begin{array}{c}
a^2x^3+\left(a+c\right)y^2 \\ 
\left(a-c\right)x^3+\left(a^2+b^4+3\right)y+c-b \end{array}
\right]$

I'm not quite sure how to solve this problem. I know how to prove whether a function is a linear transformation, but am unsure how how to find which real values result in a linear transformation.

Initially I was just thinking to take two vectors, then perform the operations and compute the values of a,b,c, but that's definitely not right. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $f$ should satisfy $f(r\begin{bmatrix}x \\ 0 \end{bmatrix})=r f(\begin{bmatrix}x \\ 0 \end{bmatrix})$ and $f(r\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ y \end{bmatrix})=r f(\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ y \end{bmatrix})$ for any real number $r$ (including $r=0$). See what that implies about what $a,b,c$ can be.

Comment: Are you able to help me work through it?

Comment: @MathsNoob If you plug in the definition of $f$ the first equation in my answer becomes $\begin{bmatrix}a^2 r^3 x^3 \\ (a-c) r^3 x^3 + c - b\end{bmatrix} = r \begin{bmatrix}a^2 x^3 \\ (a-c)x^3 + c - b\end{bmatrix}$. This needs to hold for all $x$ and $r$. When $r=0$, this implies $c-b=0$. You can also deduce that $a^2=0$ and $a-c=0$.

Comment: Okay so I've got it to the point where it's technically correct for all $a = b = c = 0$, although I know this would be accurate, but is there any possible other cases, or is this just correct?